# Guardar datos de una vista en SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buenas noches compañeros, espero me puedan orientar en este tema, tengo una aplicación en **`MVC5`**, lo que hago es cargar datos de una tabla en una vista pero quiero dejar un campo para que se agregue información adicional y posteriormente guardar esa información en otra tabla.

**Controller**:

```
    public ActionResult View(int ID)
    {
        using (dbcontext db = new dbcontext())
        {
            return View(db.TableName.Where(x => x.id == ID).ToList().AsEnumerable());
        }
    }
```

**Model**:

```
    public string Dato1{ get; set; }
    public string Dato2{ get; set; }
    public string Dato3{ get; set; }
    public double Dato4{ get; set; }
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCProject.Models.TableName>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>TituloDato1</th>
                        <th>TituloDato2</th>
                        <th>TituloDato3</th>
                        <th>TituloDato4</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var XYZ in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@XYZ.Dato1</td>
                        <td>@XYZ.Dato2</td>
                        <td>@XYZ.Dato3</td>
                        <td>@XYZ.Dato4</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="CAMPO_NUEVO"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

De esta manera me muestra los datos que quiero visualizar, ahora lo que necesito saber es como guardar esos datos, más el dato nuevo en una nueva tabla.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia.
La unica manera optima que puedo ver para resolver esto es obtener cada "campo nuevo" a traves de jquery y mandarlo en un ajax a tu controller para poder guardarlo.
Luego con la respuesta del ajax generar el  del nuevo campo que agregaste.

O tambien podrias englobar tu vista en un form para que con un boton se llame tu Action y mande guardar ese dato en especifico.

Como recomendacion tambien

```
return View(db.TableName.Where(x => x.id == ID).ToList().AsEnumerable());
```

no le hagas el to list y el enumerable, la consulta siempre regresa un enumerable

```
return View(db.TableName.Where(x => x.id == ID));
```